# How to stop youtube player when resize screen under 768px?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I would like to stop the youtube video only in mobile. I need to show it on desktop device, and hide it on mobile.

Is possibile with javascript? I'm sorry but I don't know Javascript, I need a complete code.

The Html code is:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
```

Can I integrate the windows resize function with youtube?

```
function stopVideo() {
  player.stopVideo();
```

Please Help me! If I use only a "display: none" the video disappears but you can still hear the sound.

Comment: How are you loading the youtube video? An embed link? An iframe? There are many ways to solve this issue, and you haven't provided enough information to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Sorry! I'm using iframe. 
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YQHsXMglC9A?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;loop=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;playlist=YQHsXMglC9Ak" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>